# Нам нужны [события]!

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить и синонимизировать идентичные метки:

- [событие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5) (16 вопросов)
- [события](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f) (132 вопросов)

Метку [события](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f) сделать главной.

Comment: Событие по объединению событий завершилось на удивление быстро.

Comment: @alexolut обработчик событий не дремлет. )