# Объединить метки [события], [event] и [events]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Ранее, [на Мета поднимался вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4767/262779) об объединении русскоязычных меток [события](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [событие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5) и в результате они были синонимизированны. Прошло время и появились англоязычные синонимы, которые собрали достаточно большое количество вопросов вокруг себя.
Предлагаю объединить метки [события](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f), [event](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event) и [events](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events). В качестве основной метки предлагаю оставить русскоязычную.

---

Кратко о метках:

- метка [события](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f) - 232 вопроса, есть полное описание метки;
- метка [event](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event) - 193 вопроса;
- метка [events](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events) - 134 вопроса;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создал предложение о синонимах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У кого позволяет уровень репутации и общий рейтинг ответов по метке [события](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f), [проголосуйте пожалуйста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f/synonyms).

**Update:**

Синонимы созданы модератором, вопрос решен.

Comment: Имхо, это маловероятно, так как в основном это решается модераторами. Для большей уверенности задал [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8480/176217).

Comment: @älёxölüt тогда какой вообще смысл в этой функции на сайте?

Comment: смысл появляется при достаточной активности и количестве участников. По моим наблюдениям на руСО еще нет достаточной критической массы.

Comment: Да, это пока проблема

Comment: Глянул кто по этой метке может проголосовать. Как минимум пять человек, которые тут бывают на сайте почти каждый день - могут, и они не модераторы. Но хотят ли, это другой вопрос.

Comment: Меня больше всего удивляет, что в подобных достаточно очевидных случаях модераторы так долго бездействуют. Утвердил синоним и дело с концом, вызывает сомнение - напиши ответ или хотя бы комментарий. Короче, не хотят работать бездельники. [Нужны пере-до-выборы.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7913/176217)

Comment: Написал в чат с просьбой конкретно тех у кого есть такая возможность проголосовать, сделать это