# Статистика по синонимам меток

Tags: поддержка, синонимы-меток, статистика, data-explorer

Недавний [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8477/176217) о предложении синонимов метки подтолкнул меня к вопросу:

> Сколько вообще синонимов меток было утверждено/отклонено именно голосованием обычных участников, нежели модераторским громогласным решением?

На [странице синонимов меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all) именно такой информация я не нашёл. Может она есть у модераторов или сотрудников. Или может быть её можно получить через SEDE?

Comment: Я глянул на всю эту ситуацию с синонимами и пока-что ощущение, что этот вопрос никому не интересен. Там последний раз, давненько что-то меняли.

Comment: Я думаю (цифр на руках у меня нет), что почти всегда утверждается модераторами, потому что в подобных вопросах всегда речь идёт о каких-то новосоздаваемых метках, по которым днём с огнём не сыщешь авторов с достаточной репутацией. Статистику и я бы посмотрел, чтобы ориентироваться на точные данные.

Comment: @LFC_Red imho, принудительные синонимы имеет смысл создавать только для тех меток, где среди несколько вариантов хотя бы один является действительно живой меткой - такой, которую кто-нибудь стал бы отслеживать или игнорировать. Т.е. я могу представить ситуацию "хочу видеть все вопросы по криптографии", но не могу "хочу видеть все вопросы по событиям". Живых меток мало, синонимы для них уже давно заданы, поэтому и активности никакой.

Comment: [Статистика за 2018 год](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8491/213987) подъехала.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно запросик написать типо [такого](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/958804):

```
SELECT
 ts.CreationDate,
 tt.TagName,
 st.TagName,
 ts.OwnerUserId as [User Link],
 ts.ApprovedByUserId  as [User Link],
 ts.Score
FROM 
  TagSynonyms ts
  LEFT join Tags st ON st.TagName=ts.SourceTagName
  LEFT join Tags tt ON tt.TagName=ts.TargetTagName
WHERE 
  ts.ApprovalDate is NOT NULL
  AND ts.ApprovedByUserId NOT IN (181472, 17609, 1984, 177221, 178988, 5648, 6)
ORDER BY
  tt.TagName
```

Получим списочек синонимов одобренных не модераторами и не КМ. Их там 10.

А всего у нас 349 одобренных синонима.

~3% синонимов были путём голосования утверждены, если я ничего не путаю.

Comment: Что-то там явно не так. [Слишком много шарпов](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWAdJ.jpg), у которых всего [два синонима сейчас.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/synonyms)

Comment: @älёxölüt упс, запрос количество голосов показывает. Поправил. В любом случае, я лишь направление указываю, куда копать )

Comment: Всё равно еще не очень понимаю, что делают в списке КМ и Волынкин. Предложил, но не утвердил самостоятельно?

Comment: Мне кажется, запрос можно сократить раз в 5. `SELECT * FROM TagSynonyms WHERE ApprovedByUserId = -1` дает то же самое.

Comment: Так, про Волынкина выяснилось, он еще не был модератором в сентябре 15 года, но про КМ всё ещё не ясно. И столбец синонима какой-то пустой кроме «стиль».

Comment: @älёxölüt https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/958874/approved-synonyms-exclude-moderators-and-cm «стиль» - это единственный синоним, который не был объединен, по этому он и отображается в таблице меток

Comment: Про отклонение, я так понимаю, нельзя получить статистику аналогичным образом.