# Модерация за 2018 год в цифрах

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, статистика

Наш подход к модерации сайтов — это ключевая особенность Stack Exchange:

> Мы проектируем движок сайтов сети так, чтобы все сообщества были максимально саморегулируемы. Это необходимо, чтобы объединить небольшой вклад каждого из тысяч обычных участников сообщества в единое целое.
>   -- [Теория модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/6)

Хотя на сайте есть [модераторы](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/), огромное количество *модерации* делается обычными участниками, которые используют заработанные на сайте привилегии. Так небольшой вклад в модерацию каждого, в итоговой сумме огромен.

Недавно завершился календарный год. Давайте посмотрим, как выглядит модерация в цифрах за этот период.

```
Действие                                Модераторы Сообщество¹ 
--------------------------------------- ---------- --------- 
Участников заблокировано²               37         6  
Учетных записей уничтожено              123        0  
Учетных записей удалено                 54         0  
Связь с участником                      118        0  
Отмененные блокировки                   1          0  
Проверка: предложенные правки³          36         26719  
Проверка: голоса за переоткрытие³       3          5476  
Проверка: сообщения низкого качества³   97         54357  
Проверка: запоздалые ответы³            0          3799  
Проверка: первые сообщения³             1          26511  
Проверка: очередь на закрытие³          179        35174  
Объединено меток                        27         0  
Предложено синонимов меток              35         30  
Создано синонимов меток                 44         1  
Переписано версий                       5          0  
Снято защит с вопросов                  0          1  
Переоткрыто вопросов                    146        255  
Защищено вопросов                       8          45  
Перенесено вопросов                     19         13  
Объединено вопросов                     63         0  
Вопросов отмечено тревогой⁴             50         14026  
Закрыто вопросов                        919        8664  
Обработано тревог в вопросах⁴           2112       11964  
Сообщений разблокировано                3          10  
Сообщений восстановлено                 119        1590  
Сообщений заблокировано                 63         176  
Сообщений удалено⁵                      3330       30198  
Сообщений поднято                       0          8711  
Связь с командой управляющих            3          0  
Комментариев восстановлено              292        0  
Комментариев отмечено тревогой          531        5602  
Комментариев удалено⁶                   12341      27409  
Обработано тревог в комментариях        2550       3583  
Отменено конкурсов                      2          0  
Отмечено тревогой ответов               74         10028  
Обработано тревог в ответах             7639       2463  
Комментариев преобразовано в чат        398        0
```

#### Пояснения сносок

¹ Под «сообществом» здесь подразумеваются все [участники Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users) *за исключением* [тех, у кого рядом с именем отображается ромб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) и [Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² Система блокирует участника в трех случаях: когда заново создается ранее заблокированная учетная запись, когда новая учетная запись ранее была уничтожена за спам или оскорбления, а также когда участник блокируется на всех сайтах сети разом.

³ Подсчитываются все выполненные проверки (без пропущенных), то если для  предложенной правки необходимо 2 проверки, каждая будет включена.

⁴ Включает тревоги на закрытие (но *не включает* голоса за закрытие и переоткрытие).

⁵ Не включает большое количество автоматических удалений как реакцию на ниные действия.

⁶ Включает комментарии удаленные авторами.

---

Эта публикация является аналогом [2018: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/2018-a-year-in-moderation). Огромная благодарность [@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) за SQL–запросы.

Comment: чем уничтожение учетной записи отличается от удаления?

Comment: Связь с участником целиком за модераторами, но думаю, что очень много "наводок" было предоставлено в чате участниками, в первую очередь Grundy. Простановка защит не из ромбов - это, конечно же, чаще других был Баракин. Очень интересна статистика по комментариям, особенно по восстановленным. А в целом закономерность проста: там где могут делать не только модераторы - модераторы редко вмешиваются, в основном это мы с вами модерируем.

Comment: @Grundy удаление оставляет часть контента (посты с положительным рейтингом, может быть что-то ещё). Уничтожение сносит все начисто.

Comment: Как сообщество могло заблокировать участников? Это случаи самоподрыва что ли?

Comment: @AK, вероятнее всего тревогой Спам

Comment: Кто-нибудь знает цифру, сколько за год зарегистрировалось пользователей? Ну так, чтобы сравнить с сотней удалённых-заблокированных. Явно величины несопоставимые, но для лучшего понимания.

Comment: И ещё очень хочется понимать величину автоматически грохнутых комментариев, если 12к было грохнуто модераторами и ещё 24к удалены участниками (сами свои удаляли?)

Comment: В целом статистика похожа на статистику большого stackoverflow, разумеется со скидкой на масштаб. Каких-то местных аномалий не усматриваю пока, всё в русле общих тенденций.

Comment: @AK, *`"Кто-нибудь знает цифру, сколько за год зарегистрировалось пользователей?"`* -- недавно было где-то тут число, точно не помню, но немного меньше 40K

Comment: @avp Совершенно верно! Я писал эту цифру в [новогодней публикации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8461/6).

Comment: @AK Поясните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос про удаленные комментарии, если он еще остался.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Сколько было автоматически удалённых комментариев? Интересно сопоставить цифры скрипта с данной статистикой.