# Модерация за 2019 год в цифрах

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, статистика

Наш подход к модерации сайтов — это ключевая особенность Stack Exchange:

> Мы проектируем движок сайтов сети так, чтобы все сообщества были максимально саморегулируемы. Это необходимо, чтобы объединить небольшой вклад каждого из тысяч обычных участников сообщества в единое целое.
>   -- [Теория модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/6)

Хотя на сайте есть [модераторы](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/), огромное количество *модерации* делается обычными участниками, которые используют заработанные на сайте привилегии. Так небольшой вклад в модерацию каждого, в итоговой сумме огромен.

Недавно завершился календарный год. Давайте посмотрим, как выглядит модерация в цифрах за этот период.

```
Действие                                Модераторы Сообщество¹ 
--------------------------------------- ---------- --------- 
Участников заблокировано²               43         5  
Учётных записей уничтожено³             44         0
Учётных записей удалено                 29         0  
Связь с участником                      173        0  
Отмененные блокировки                   2          0  
Проверка⁴: предложенные правки          182        23319  
Проверка⁴: голоса за переоткрытие       116        12752  
Проверка⁴: сообщения низкого качества   465        50729  
Проверка⁴: запоздалые ответы            8          4786  
Проверка⁴: первые сообщения             399        27384  
Проверка⁴: очередь на закрытие          1448       36209  
Объединено меток                        54         0  
Предложено синонимов меток              19         16  
Создано синонимов меток                 41         4  
Переписано версий                       17         0  
Снято защит с вопросов                  0          1  
Переоткрыто вопросов                    179        208  
Защищено вопросов                       6          58  
Перенесено вопросов                     16         13  
Объединено вопросов                     47         0  
Вопросов отмечено тревогой⁵             57         14248  
Закрыто вопросов                        1004       11474  
Обработано тревог в вопросах⁵           2159       11999  
Сообщений разблокировано                2          5  
Сообщений восстановлено                 131        1419  
Сообщений заблокировано                 34         160  
Сообщений удалено⁶                      2658       33928  
Сообщений поднято                       0          8617  
Связь с командой управляющих            4          0  
Комментариев восстановлено              118        0  
Комментариев отмечено тревогой          151        4661  
Комментариев удалено⁶                   10552      25680  
Обработано тревог в комментариях        2178       2634  
Отменено конкурсов                      5          0  
Отмечено тревогой ответов               43         8064  
Обработано тревог в ответах             6138       1969  
Комментариев преобразовано в чат        322        0
```

#### Пояснения сносок

¹ Под «сообществом» здесь подразумеваются все [участники Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users) *за исключением* [тех, у кого рядом с именем отображается ромб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) и [Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² Система блокирует участника в трёх случаях: когда заново создаётся ранее заблокированная учётная запись, когда новая учётная запись ранее была уничтожена за спам или оскорбления, а также когда участник блокируется на всех сайтах сети разом.

³ Уничтоженная учётная запись — это запись, которая удаляется со всем созданным ей содержимым: вопросами, ответами, комментариями. [Обычно используется при удалении спама.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ Подсчитываются все выполненные проверки (без пропущенных), так если для  предложенной правки необходимо 2 проверки, каждая будет включена.

⁵ Включает тревоги на закрытие (но *не включает* голоса за закрытие и переоткрытие).

⁶ Не включает большое количество автоматических удалений как реакцию на иные действия.

⁷ Включает комментарии удалённые авторами.

#### Дополнительно

- Хотите узнать как меняются данные со временем? Обратите внимание на данные за прошлый год: [Модерация за 2018 год в цифрах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8491/6).
- Вы также можете посмотреть [на аналогичный отчёт для других сайтов сети](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22).
- Или изучить [детальную информацию о закрытых и повторно открытых вопросах на всех сайтах сети](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing).

Желаем вам счастливого нового года! =)

---

Эта публикация является аналогом [2019: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392550/2019-a-year-in-moderation). Огромная благодарность [@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) за SQL–запросы.

Comment: Я смотрю, в этом году модераторы поактивнее в очередях стали :D

Comment: "Комментариев преобразовано в чат        322" - подозрительно. Преобразуют в чат обычно после 20+ сообщений. Эта статистика говорит, что всего ~15 постов было, где комментарии в чат были перенесены? Уверен, что даже я один больше 15 переносов (~300 комментариев) комментариев в чат сделал. Может тут речь именно про число постов?

Comment: Очень рад, что появилась возможность сравнить с [прошлым периодом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8491/213987), теперь хорошо видно, что в основном цифры сопоставимые, резких скачков нет.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica В оригинале *"All comments on a post moved to chat"*, так что похоже действительно число постов.

Comment: Как сообщество может само заблокировать участника?